# How do I edit a specific word in my text document?

Tags: java, csv, arraylist, replace

As of now, my code only edits words if they are separated by a return. If I separate words via space or a comma, they do not get replaced.

E.G. If I have 'hey' on one line, and 'hi' on the next. My code can replace both of them if I wanted. However, if I have 'hey' on one line, and 'hi' separated by a comma next to 'hey', my code does not replace either.

The goal of my code is to replace words within a .CSV file but if my code cannot replace words delimited by a comma or space, then it doesn't work.

Here's my code that activates at the push of a button:

```
try{
    // Input the file location into Path variable 'p'
    Path p = Paths.get("test test.txt");
    //Path p = Paths.get("tiger.csv");

    //Read the whole file to a ArrayList
    List<String> fileContent = new ArrayList<>(Files.readAllLines(p));

    //Converting user input from editSerialField to a string
    String strSerial = editSerialField.getText();
    //Converting user input from editLocationField to a string
    String strLocation = editLocationField.getText();

    //This structure looks for a duplicate in the text file, if so, replaces it with the user input from editLocationField.
    for (int i = 0; i < fileContent.size(); i++)
    {
        if (fileContent.get(i).equals(strSerial))
        {
            fileContent.set(i, strLocation);
            break;
        }

    }

    // write the new String with the replaced line OVER the same file
    Files.write(p, fileContent);

    }catch(IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

How can I edit words delimited by a comma or space? Also, it would be neat if I could replace words regardless if they're uppercase or lowercase, how do I carry this out?

Thank you.

Comment: It appears you're only matching /entire lines/ against known strings, whereas you say you are trying to replace individual words.   You'd have to look into the line and pick out the words, of course, to replace individual words.    Consider using the `Scanner` class or a CSV parser instead of doing the string manipulation yourself...

Comment: When I'm using `Scanner`, it cannot be converted to 'path'. `List<String> fileContent = new ArrayList<>(Files.readAllLines(s));` whereas 's' is `Scanner s = new Scanner("test test.txt");`. Am I meant to be using Scanner in a different manner in order to read the whole file?

Comment: Scanner functionality takes the place of `Files.readAllLines()`, the `Scanner` does the reading.  See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Comment: Looks like I'll have to re-write my code for this `Scanner` function. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Engage regex:

```
fileContent.replaceAll(s -> s.replaceAll("(?i)\\b" + strSerial + "\\b", strLocation));
```

Adding `\b`, which means "word boundary", to both ends of the search term means only *whole words* will be replaced.

Adding `(?i)` means "ignore case".

Answer (score 0):

In your code where you have the following:

```
//Read the whole file to a ArrayList
List<String> fileContent = new ArrayList<>(Files.readAllLines(p));
```

I'm guessing that you really meant this:

```
//Read the whole file to a ArrayList
List<String> fileContent = Files.readAllLines(p);
```

Then when looping over each line just check and see if each one contains something your interested in. You can also just split each of your lines into words and then check each word all with java 8 streams.

Comment: No, he absolutely cannot.  That would replace /substrings within words/ as well as entire words.

Comment: correct. he would need to split each line into words and then update as needed.